# Connect to PostgreSQL-base by Unix-Socket

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.2, unix-socket

I use TCP-connection to a remote PostgreSQL using:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://remotehost.com/test_psql", "admin", "password");
```

And it working successfully.

But I cant use UNIX-Socket connection

I add to pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>no.fiken.oss.junixsocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>junixsocket-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And change url to this:

```
 jdbc:postgresql:test_psql?socketFactory=org.newsclub.net.unix.socketfactory.PostgresqlAFUNIXSocketFactory&socketFactoryArg" +
            "=/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I receive in stack now:

```
org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketException: No such file or directory (socket: /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432)
```

But this directory and file are exist. Because when I run 'netstat -nlp | grep 5432', I receive:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               
 LISTEN      14174/postgres      
 tcp6       0      0 :::54320                :::*                    
 LISTEN      15824/docker-proxy  
 tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    
 LISTEN      14174/postgres      
 unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1260991417 
 14174/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

However, 5432 in above table are marked red.

Comment: Unrelated: have you considered upgrading your postgres version? using 9.2 you're really far behind (2012?)

Comment: Which JDBC driver version are you using? And please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** error message you get. [As documented in the driver manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#unix%20sockets) you need an additional library to make Unix Sockets work with the JDBC driver.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no possibility to upgrade postgres vertion, as my server-panel ("Plesk") supports only this version...

Comment: in dependencies  postgresql   42.2.9.jre6

Comment: I edited question with log

Answer (score 0):

The exception mentions `socket: /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` (not **/var/** run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432), so maybe there's a command-line parsing issue related to the `&` character in that string?

But maybe `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run`. Can you access `/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` through other means?

Since that `no.fiken.oss.junixsocket` variant is a quite old fork of junixsocket, also try again with the latest original, junixsocket 2.5.2.

Details on usage here: https://kohlschutter.github.io/junixsocket/dependency.html